# Android OnClick and OnclickListner

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. My current application crashes on onClick event from the XML, but it seems to work just fine with onClickListner.

public static String URL_WEB;
    NsdUtils mNsdUtils;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final NsdUtils mNsdUtils = new NsdUtils(this);
    mNsdUtils.initializeNsd();
    /*Button button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_discover_networks);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            mNsdUtils.discoverServices();
        }
    });*/
}

public void onClickDiscover(View view){
    mNsdUtils.discoverServices();
}
```

Logs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.implicitintents, PID: 6397
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.implicitintents.Utils.NsdUtils.discoverServices()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.android.implicitintents.MainActivity.onClickDiscoverAura(MainActivity.java:40)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

It seems I am missing a very basic detail. Any help will be great.

NsdUtils

```
public class NsdUtils {
    Context mContext;

    NsdManager mNsdManager;
    NsdManager.ResolveListener mResolveListener;
    NsdManager.DiscoveryListener mDiscoveryListener;


    //To find all the available networks SERVICE_TYPE = "_services._dns-sd._udp"
    public static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp";

    public static final String TAG = "NsdUtils";
    public String mServiceName = "_hap";

    NsdServiceInfo mService;

    public NsdUtils(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mNsdManager = (NsdManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
    }

    public void initializeNsd() {
        initializeDiscoveryListener();
        initializeResolveListener();
    }

    public void initializeDiscoveryListener() {
        mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDiscoveryStarted(String regType) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery started " + regType);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success" + service);

                if(!service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unknown Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
                }
                else if(service.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Same Machine: " + mServiceName);
                }
                else if(service.getServiceName().contains(mServiceName)){
                    mNsdManager.resolveService(service, mResolveListener);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo service) {
                Log.e(TAG, "service lost" + service);
                if (mService == service) {
                    mService = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
                mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
                mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
            }
        };
    }

    public void initializeResolveListener() {
        mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {

            @Override
            public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

                if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
                    return;
                }
                mService = serviceInfo;
            }
        };
    }

    public void stopDiscovery() {
        mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
    }

    public NsdServiceInfo getChosenServiceInfo() {
        return mService;
    }

    public void discoverServices() {
        mNsdManager.discoverServices(
                SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_discover_networks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:onClick="onClickDiscover"
    android:text="Discover Networks"/>
```

Comment: please post ur xml code also full activity class

Comment: maybe you are giving wrong button id. Post your xml file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make `mNsdUtils` to be a member field if it should be accessed from the outside of the function?

The root cause saying `mNsdUtils` is null from the `MainActivity.onClickDiscover()` implementation.

Implement in the method itself, as the context is different throwing a null pointer exception.

A small tip for you: read the stack trace and find your source code(for your case, MainActivity.java) to locate what was the first error from bottom to up.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.implicitintents.Utils.NsdUtils.discoverServices()' on a null object reference
  at com.example.android.implicitintents.MainActivity.onClickDiscoverAura(MainActivity.java:40)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is the one you need.

`at com.example.android.implicitintents.MainActivity.onClickDiscoverAura(MainActivity.java:40)`

Comment: Thanks thoshr I found my mistake. Now, it seemed silly to ask such a question.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with onClick. Please read your following log :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.implicitintents.Utils.NsdUtils.discoverServices()' on a null object reference

It means that inside onClick "mNsdUtils" is null. For more assistance please post your NsdUtils class.

Do the following and your app won't crash:

```
public void onClickDiscover(View view){
if(mNsdUtils != null)                  //add this line
mNsdUtils.discoverServices();
  }
```

Comment: I have added the NsdUtils

Answer (score 0):

onClickListener is working just fine. You have to instantiate NSD object globally and then use it.